# vue.js reuse of 3d.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

New to Vue.js (using version 2).

I would like to reuse the [bubble-chart](https://github.com/phuonghuynh/bubble-chart) project in vue js. 
It has allot of goodies inside like 3D.js and some jQuery but it's ok for me for now (not being Vue.js).

I understand that one way is to create parallel component of Vue.js from scratch.
What is the correct way to import/reuse none Vue projects?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of JQuery date picker wrapped in vue component. This way you created reusable component where you can use 'props' for passing values from rest of vue project. Same thing you can do for bubble chart. This is the easiest implementation for your needs.

```
 <template>
    <input class="datepicker-input btn-gray-gredient" type="text" readonly/>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        props: ['value'],
        mounted: function () {
            /**
             * Getting today's date
             */
            var today = new Date();
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            today = ((today.getDate() < 10) ? ('0' + today.getDate()) : today.getDate()) + '-' + ((today.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1) : (today.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' + today.getFullYear();
            /**
             * JQuery wrapped date picker
             */
            var self = this;
            $('.datepicker-input').on('click', function() {
                $('.fa-calendar').click();
            });

            /**
             * Setting up datepicker with default properties
             */
            $(self.$el)
                .datepicker({ value: today, iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome', format: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }) // init datepicker
                .trigger('change')
                .on('change', function () { // emit event on change.
                    self.$emit('input', this.value);
                });
        },
        watch: {
            value: function (value) {
                $(this.$el).val(value);
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el).datepicker('destroy');
        }
    }
</script>
```